# Need to set an if, where array is NOT equal to previous array numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to learn Javascript by doing some simple projects. Here I am doing BINGO card generator. It generates numbers in random, in every column minimal number is increased by 15, and it works fine, but I can't wrap my head around how should I identify duplicates of numbers in array, so that if it finds a duplicate, it should run code again.

Here is code:

```js
var numArr = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4);
var newNumArr = new Array();
var num = 0;

function initialize() {
 for(i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   fillCard(i);
 }
}

function fillCard(i) {
 newNumArr[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15 + numArr[i] * 15) + 1);
   if(newNumArr[num] != true) {
      document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = num;
      newNumArr[num] = true;
    } else {
      fillCard(i);
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ee9ca7;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

div#info {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 4.5vh auto;
}

p {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-right: 2.5vw;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 1vw;
 text-align: justify;
 justify-content: inter-word;
}

p span{
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 7.5vw;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}

input {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid #1565c0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 2vh;
 width: 65%;
 height: 5vh;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-bottom: 1vh;
 position: relative;
}

input:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

div#bingoCard {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top: 3vw;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
}

div#bingoCard table{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div#bingoCard table td {
 text-align: center;
 width: 7.5vw;
 height: 15vh;
 background-color: #076585;
 color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

div#bingoCard table td:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

.disabled {
 background: #2196f3 !important;
 border: 5px solid #1565c0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
BINGO kortelių generatorius ir žaidimas.
Sugeneruoja nepasikartojančius skaičius kiekviename langelyje.

Pirmas stulpelis 1 - 15;
Antras stulpelis 16 - 30;
Trečias stulpelis 31 - 45;
Ketvirtas stulpelis 46 - 60;
Penktas stulpelis 61 - 75;

Vidurinis lentelės langelis iškarto turi būti užimtas.

Galimybė nusistatyti, kiek skaičių bus išridenta.
Paspaudus 'START', pradedami ridenti skaičiai, kas 5 sek. naujas skaičius.
Atsiranda mygtukas 'B!NGO'.
Žymime išridentus skaičius.

KKOMBINACIJOS:
  Stulpeliai:
    d0 d1 d2 d3 d4;
    d5 d6 d7 d8 d9;
    d10 d11 d12 d13 d14;
    d15 d16 d17 d18 d19;
    d20 d21 d22 d23 d24;

  Eilutės:
    d0 d5 d10 d15 d20;
    d1 d6 d11 d16 d21;
    d2 d7 d12 d17 d22;
    d3 d8 d12 d18 d23;
    d4 d9 d13 d19 d24;

  Įstrižainės:
    d0 d6 d12 d18 d24;
    d4 d8 d12 d16 d20;


Surinkus vieną iš kombinacijų, spaudžiame 'B!NGO'.

Tuomet PROGRAMA TIKRINA:
Išridentus skaičius;
Pažymėtus skaičius;
Ar išridenti ir pažymėti skaičiai sutampa;
Ar sutampantys skaičiai sudaro kokią nors kombinaciją.

Jei sudaro, tai pranešama, kad buvo laimėta.
Jei nesudaro, tai neleidžiama žymėti skaičių 10 sekundžių.

Pasibaigus visiems ridenamiems skaičiams, baigiamas žaidimas.

Tikrinama ar yra sudarytos kombinacijos,
nežiūrint į tai ar yra pažymėtas skaičius.

Jei buvo išridentas skaičius, bet nepažymėtas,
jis pažymimas kita spalva.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>B!NGO - Online BINGO Card Generator</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info">
    <h1>B!NGO</h1>
    <p><span>Rules of BINGO:</span><br>
    You have to stamp the cells which has numbers same as numbers that appear
 on the right side. When you stamp a column, a row or diagonally press
 BINGO!</p>
 <input type="button" name="numbers" value="GENERATE" id="generate"
     onclick="initialize();">
    <input type="button" name="play" value="START">
    <input type="button" name="print" value="PRINT">
    <p id="test"></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bingoCard">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td id="d0" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d5" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d10" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d14" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d19" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d1" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d6" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d11" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d15" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d20" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d2" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d7" class="low"></td>
       <td class="mid disabled">FREE</td>
       <td id="d16" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d21" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d3" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d8" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d12" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d17" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d22" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d4" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d9" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d13" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d18" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d23" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I EDITED JS file. Now it works, but only for 3 times, if I want generate new numbers more times it does not do anything.

Comment: Check to see if the number is used before adding it...

Comment: @epascarello, or even better, create array with all numbers and pop each number which is randomly picked for cell.. *not familiar with how bingo works btw

Answer (score 0):

You can check the random generated number if its present in the array or not.. if its present then just get a another random number it will ensure you don't get duplicate as done below.
let me know if this helps

```js
var numArr = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4);
var newNumArr = new Array();
var num = 0;

function initialize() {
 for(i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   fillCard(i);
 }
}

function fillCard(i) {
  var temp = findNonDuplicateRandom()
   
   
   newNumArr[i]=temp;
    if(newNumArr[i] != true) {
      document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = newNumArr[i];
    } else {
      fillCard(i);
    }
}

function findNonDuplicateRandom(){
  var isDuplicate=false;
   var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15 + numArr[i] * 15) + 1);
   
   var x=newNumArr.find(t=>t==temp);
   if(x){
      //console.log("duplicate"+temp);
        return findNonDuplicateRandom();
      }
     else
     {
       //console.log("no duplicate"+temp);
       return temp;
      }

   
}
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ee9ca7;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

div#info {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 4.5vh auto;
}

p {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-right: 2.5vw;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 1vw;
 text-align: justify;
 justify-content: inter-word;
}

p span{
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 7.5vw;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}

input {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid #1565c0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 2vh;
 width: 65%;
 height: 5vh;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-bottom: 1vh;
 position: relative;
}

input:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

div#bingoCard {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top: 3vw;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
}

div#bingoCard table{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div#bingoCard table td {
 text-align: center;
 width: 7.5vw;
 height: 15vh;
 background-color: #076585;
 color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

div#bingoCard table td:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

.disabled {
 background: #2196f3 !important;
 border: 5px solid #1565c0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>B!NGO - Online BINGO Card Generator</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info">
    <h1>B!NGO</h1>
    <p><span>Rules of BINGO:</span><br>
    You have to stamp the cells which has numbers same as numbers that appear
 on the right side. When you stamp a column, a row or diagonally press
 BINGO!</p>
 <input type="button" name="numbers" value="GENERATE" id="generate"
     onclick="initialize();">
    <input type="button" name="play" value="START">
    <input type="button" name="print" value="PRINT">
    <p id="test"></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bingoCard">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td id="d0" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d5" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d10" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d14" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d19" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d1" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d6" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d11" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d15" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d20" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d2" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d7" class="low"></td>
       <td class="mid disabled">FREE</td>
       <td id="d16" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d21" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d3" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d8" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d12" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d17" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d22" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d4" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d9" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d13" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d18" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d23" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed code a bit, now it looks like this:

`   if(newNumArr[num] != true) {`
 `     document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = num;`
  `    newNumArr[num] = true;`
   ` } else {`
    `  fillCard(i);`
    `}`
`}`
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. I've simplified a bit and added some comments to hopefully help you understand the logic a bit better.

FYI the reason it was failing after a few runs is because you weren't resetting the `newNumArr` on `initialize`, so it was eventually marking all the numbers as used.

```js
// keep a list of the numbers that have already been used
var usedNumbers = [];

function initialize() {
  // reset the list each time generate is clicked
  usedNumbers = []; 
 for(i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   fillCard(i);
 }
}

function fillCard(i) {
  var valueFound = false;
  // keep trying to get a random value until we find a unique one
  while (!valueFound) {
    var num = Math.ceil((Math.random() + Math.floor(i / 5)) * 15);
    // only continue if the random number is not already present
    if(usedNumbers.indexOf(num) === -1) {
      document.getElementById('d' + i).innerHTML = num;
      // add this number to the array of used numbers
      usedNumbers.push(num);
      valueFound = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ee9ca7;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

div#info {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 4.5vh auto;
}

p {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-right: 2.5vw;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 1vw;
 text-align: justify;
 justify-content: inter-word;
}

p span{
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 7.5vw;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}

input {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 3px solid #1565c0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 2vh;
 width: 65%;
 height: 5vh;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-bottom: 1vh;
 position: relative;
}

input:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

div#bingoCard {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top: 3vw;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
}

div#bingoCard table{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div#bingoCard table td {
 text-align: center;
 width: 7.5vw;
 height: 15vh;
 background-color: #076585;
 color: #fafafa;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

div#bingoCard table td:hover {
 background-color: #1e88e5;
}

.disabled {
 background: #2196f3 !important;
 border: 5px solid #1565c0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
BINGO kortelių generatorius ir žaidimas.
Sugeneruoja nepasikartojančius skaičius kiekviename langelyje.

Pirmas stulpelis 1 - 15;
Antras stulpelis 16 - 30;
Trečias stulpelis 31 - 45;
Ketvirtas stulpelis 46 - 60;
Penktas stulpelis 61 - 75;

Vidurinis lentelės langelis iškarto turi būti užimtas.

Galimybė nusistatyti, kiek skaičių bus išridenta.
Paspaudus 'START', pradedami ridenti skaičiai, kas 5 sek. naujas skaičius.
Atsiranda mygtukas 'B!NGO'.
Žymime išridentus skaičius.

KKOMBINACIJOS:
  Stulpeliai:
    d0 d1 d2 d3 d4;
    d5 d6 d7 d8 d9;
    d10 d11 d12 d13 d14;
    d15 d16 d17 d18 d19;
    d20 d21 d22 d23 d24;

  Eilutės:
    d0 d5 d10 d15 d20;
    d1 d6 d11 d16 d21;
    d2 d7 d12 d17 d22;
    d3 d8 d12 d18 d23;
    d4 d9 d13 d19 d24;

  Įstrižainės:
    d0 d6 d12 d18 d24;
    d4 d8 d12 d16 d20;


Surinkus vieną iš kombinacijų, spaudžiame 'B!NGO'.

Tuomet PROGRAMA TIKRINA:
Išridentus skaičius;
Pažymėtus skaičius;
Ar išridenti ir pažymėti skaičiai sutampa;
Ar sutampantys skaičiai sudaro kokią nors kombinaciją.

Jei sudaro, tai pranešama, kad buvo laimėta.
Jei nesudaro, tai neleidžiama žymėti skaičių 10 sekundžių.

Pasibaigus visiems ridenamiems skaičiams, baigiamas žaidimas.

Tikrinama ar yra sudarytos kombinacijos,
nežiūrint į tai ar yra pažymėtas skaičius.

Jei buvo išridentas skaičius, bet nepažymėtas,
jis pažymimas kita spalva.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>B!NGO - Online BINGO Card Generator</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info">
    <h1>B!NGO</h1>
    <p><span>Rules of BINGO:</span><br>
    You have to stamp the cells which has numbers same as numbers that appear
 on the right side. When you stamp a column, a row or diagonally press
 BINGO!</p>
 <input type="button" name="numbers" value="GENERATE" id="generate"
     onclick="initialize();">
    <input type="button" name="play" value="START">
    <input type="button" name="print" value="PRINT">
    <p id="test"></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bingoCard">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td id="d0" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d5" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d10" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d14" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d19" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d1" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d6" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d11" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d15" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d20" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d2" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d7" class="low"></td>
       <td class="mid disabled">FREE</td>
       <td id="d16" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d21" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d3" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d8" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d12" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d17" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d22" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="d4" class="lowest"></td>
       <td id="d9" class="low"></td>
       <td id="d13" class="mid"></td>
       <td id="d18" class="high"></td>
       <td id="d23" class="highest"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```